# (Too) simple derivation for the canonical ensemble?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I'm currently reading a book from Wilhelm Brenig about statistical mechanics. He gives a short argument for the derivation of the probability distribution of the canonical ensemble before discussing it more detailed later. I will give a summary:

We have a system in a stationary eigenstate of the Hamiltonian. We label the eigenenergies as $E_n$, and we want to know the probability $\rho(E_n)$ that the system has this energy. For this, we separate the system in two subsystems $1$ and $2$ with energies $E_{1m}$ and $E_{2n}$ with the help of a wall between them. The wall let's energy from one side to the other. We call the energy of the whole system $E_{mn}$. Assuming the interaction between the two subsystems is negligible, we get 
$$E_{mn} = E_{1m}+E_{2m}.$$
Then the subsystems are statistically independent, which means
$$\rho(E_{mn})=\rho(E_{1m})\cdot \rho(E_{2n}).$$
This is the part where I struggle. Let's take, e.g., $E_{mn} = E$. Then I think that we should find all pairs of states $(E_{1m},E_{2n})$ with $E = E_{1m}+E_{2m}$. Then we can find the probability that the whole system has energy $E$ with $$\rho(E)=\sum_{pairs} \rho(E_{1m})\rho(E_{2m}).$$ But the sum over all pairs is missing in Brenig's book. Why can we assume that only one such pair exists? Maybe it helps if I give the further argumentation of the book:

If we take the logarithm of $\rho(E_{mn})=\rho(E_{1m})\cdot \rho(E_{2n})$, we get 
$$\ln \rho(E_{mn}) = \ln \rho(E_{1m}) + \ln \rho(E_{2n}).$$ This means the logarithm of the probability distribution is a linear function in the energy, e.g., $\ln \rho(E_n) = -\beta E_n.$ Exponentiation gives $$\rho(E_n) = \frac{e^{-\beta E_n}}{Z},$$ where $Z$ is given by normalization.

Comment: I don't have access to the text, but I wonder if the author perhaps starts by ignoring the effects of degeneracy?

Comment: It could be. But there is nothing mentioned about degeneracy in the text of the book.